# How to swap the sprite in the CCSprite object in Cocos2d-X

Tags: ccsprite, cocos2d-x

I  have an object that inherited from CCSprite.
I want from inside this object to change the image.

How do I change the image (sprite) without creating a new CCSprite object in Cocos2d-X?

Thanks, 
Adrian.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
mySprite->setTexture(CCTextureCache::sharedTextureCache()->addImage("newImage.png"));
```

No need to alter your custom class..  Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: Yeah it does. Its more elegant than the way I used to fix my problem. Thanks.

Comment: accept the answer and close it else people will keep posting answers.. :)

Answer (score 2):

Works for me:

```
mySprite->setDisplayFrame(CCSpriteFrameCache::sharedSpriteFrameCache()->spriteFrameByName("frame_name"));
```

Before you need to load you sprites in cache:

```
CCSpriteFrameCache::sharedSpriteFrameCache()->addSpriteFramesWithFile("sprite_atlas.plist");
```

Comment: For cocos2d-x 3.x: `mySprite->setSpriteFrame("frame_name");`

Answer (score 1):

I found out, and I leave it here in case somebody gets stuck with the same problem:

**Inside your object that's inherited from CCSprite  object, write a function as follows**

```
void MyObject::UpdateImage(Char * PngName)
{
   /* Create Image */
   CCImage *MyImage = new CCImage();
   MyImage->initWithImageFile( PngName ); /*the pngName is an image file in your resource folder */

   /* Create Texture from Image */
   CCTexture2D *MyTexture = new CCTexture2D();
   MyTexture->initWithImage(MyImage);

   /* Set the Texture */
   this->setTexture(MyTexture);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since "CCTextureCache::sharedTextureCache()" is now deprecated (v.3.13.1) you'd better get the texture cache from the Director:

```
auto texture = Director::getInstance()->getTextureCache()->addImage(filePath);

if (texture)
{
    yourSprite->setTexture(texture);
}
```

Source: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Texture_Cache